# Why does VS2008 suggest editing a non-existent file?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, warnings, .net-cf-3.5

One of my VS 2008 projects shows several warning lines in the Output window like this:

*Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Windows.Forms, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac, Retargetable=Yes" from Version "1.0.5000.0" [] to Version "3.5.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Windows.Forms.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.*

...and yet there is no app.config file for this project. What does it really want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is referencing something that references v1.0.5000.0 of System.Windows.Forms, but you do not have that version. The warning is suggesting that you add a remapping to v3.5.0.0 of that assembly so that it will work properly. You do this in the `app.config` file. It is suggesting that you add this file to your project and add the mapping to it.

Something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="969db8053d3322ac" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.5000.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, adrianbanks, but that link does not describe what exactly to put in an app.config file (I don't know what syntax it's expecting, since I don't have one to use as a basis/template).

Comment: @ClayShannon: I've added an example.